# Can you navigate to a record detail App Builder page if the view action has been overridden?

Tags: lightning-web-components, app-builder

I'm interested in overriding the view action for an object. I'm going to use an LWC inside of an Aura component for the override.

The object has multiple record types. I would like to use the Aura component for one record type, but use the standard record detail App Builder page for the other record type.

While I understand that the Aura component can determine the record type and have conditional behavior based on that, I'm not sure it helps because I don't know how to navigate to a Record Detail App Builder page if the view action is overridden. Is there a way to do that, or does the override completely remove the ability to see the Record Detail App Builder page?

Alternatively, if I'm missing a better approach here that would also be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Either Aura or LWC you can use Lightning Data Service to Determine RecordType of Record.
   Aura - force:recordData
   LWC - getRecord wire adapter. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record)
2. Overriding the Object View will override completely. We cannot separate the behavior for each individual record Type. Instead, In the Lightning Record Page, use conditional visibility filters - hide and display components based on the record type.